# Tetration of Alephs

Tags: set-theory, tetration

Does this even mean anything?

$\underbrace{x^{x^{x^{...^{x^x}}}}}_n$

Where $n = \aleph_0$?

Because I "know" it converges when (say) $x = .5$ and $n \to \infty$

Comment: You probably want $n=\omega$ as an ordinal, rather than $\aleph_0$ as a cardinal. In either case, cardinals and ordinals and $\infty$ are **not** the same thing.

Comment: The answer is in the question: it makes sense when the sequence $u_n=\underbrace{x^{x^{x^{...^{x^x}}}}}_n$ converges.

Comment: See also my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90758/the-aleph-numbers-and-infinity-in-calculus/

Comment: ok, but you can do $1 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, right? why is that allowed? why must that not be an ordinal number?

Comment: Yes, and you can do many other things too.

Comment: why is it that you "need" an ordinal in the tetration case and not in the addition case?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, note that a cardinal is also an ordinal.

Comment: @arbautjc: Yes, if it's an initial ordinal, but even then, cardinal operations and ordinal operations are not the same in general.

Comment: @arbautjc: No. It's not.

Answer (score 2):

This is meaningful for **ordinal numbers only**.  This operation has no meaning in cardinal arithmetic (explained below).  We can define an operation $\uparrow \uparrow$ using transfinite recursion as follows:

$$\alpha \uparrow \uparrow 0 = 1$$

$$\alpha \uparrow \uparrow \beta + 1 = \alpha^{ \alpha \uparrow \uparrow \beta} $$

$$\alpha \uparrow \uparrow \gamma = \sup \{ \alpha \uparrow \uparrow \beta : \beta < \gamma \} \text{ where $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal}$$

**EDIT**: This is only meaningful if we are talking about this as an operation with *ordinal* numbers.  This has no meaning for cardinal numbers.  However, we can talk about this operation with the ordinal number $\omega$, for example.

The problem is that we want our hypothetical operation $2\uparrow \uparrow \omega$ or $2 \uparrow \uparrow \aleph_0$ to be a **fixed point** so that $2^{ 2 \uparrow \uparrow \omega } = 2 \uparrow \uparrow \omega$.  But if $\aleph_\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then $2^{\aleph_\kappa} \ne \aleph_\kappa$ so our operation would have no fixed points.

Comment: Note that $\aleph_0$ is **not** an ordinal. It's a cardinal.

Comment: ok, but you can do $1 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, right? why is that allowed? why must that not be an ordinal number?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, note that a cardinal is also an ordinal.

Comment: @arbautjc How so?

Comment: @HoraceLoeb There's addition of quantities, and addition of positions. If you were adding the position 1 to the position $\omega$, you would expect it to be distinct from $\omega$. That is, ordinal addition is affine.

Comment: Well, actually $1 + \omega = \omega \ne \omega + 1$.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon That makes sense. Then you can also talk about the index to sequences in the limit.

Comment: @arbautjc: Cardinals are not ordinals. The arithmetical systems are **completely** different in every aspect when it comes to infinite ordinals and infinite cardinals.

Comment: @Asaf Many people identify cardinals with initial ordinals.  I would go so far as to say this is the standard definition in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I believe Asaf is referring to the difference between ordinal and cardinal arithmetic: the two systems have completely different rules for addition, multiplication, and exponentiation.

Comment: @Trevor: What Andrew said. Also, pack the book!

Comment: Well, he also said that.  But twice he said that cardinals are not ordinals, which is what I am disagreeing with (in the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ context.)

Comment: @Asaf Thanks for the remainder about the book

Comment: @Trevor: I meant as arithmetical systems, as my third clarification. Third time the charm and all that...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *cardinal* numbers, but hyperoperations on *ordinal* numbers  have been studied, e.g. by John Doner and Alfred Tarski, An extended arithmetic of ordinal numbers, Fund. Math. 65 (1969), 95–127. That paper is freely available here:

http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/mathbwn/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv65i1p10bwm

Answer (score 0):

For a cardinal/combinatorial perspective, note that $2 \uparrow \uparrow n = | V_{n+1} | = 2^{|V_n|}$ for finite $n$, where $V_n$ is stage $n$ of the [cumulative hierarchy of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe). We could extend this to transfinite $n$. There might also be a sensible way to extend it to bases other than 2.

A problem here is that the arithmetic we would expect seems to be inconsistent for transfinite cardinals. For instance,
\begin{align}
2 \uparrow \uparrow \aleph_0
&= 2 \uparrow \uparrow (\aleph_0 + 1) \\
&= 2^{2 \uparrow \uparrow \aleph_0} \\
&> 2 \uparrow \uparrow \aleph_0 & \text{(Cantor's theorem)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$, we can generalize and have that $\wp(κ) = κ ↑↑ 2$. Technically, $\aleph_0 ↑↑ \aleph_0 = \beth_{\omega}$ (I think someone else on this site noted this elsewhere, but I can't find the posting).
You can also use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to iterate self-exponentiation of $\aleph_0$ and get the $\beth_n$ from this.

Tetration also shows up in accounts of ultrafilters, via the expression "2<sup>2<sup>κ</sup></sup>." See e.g. [page 4 of this article](https://users.metu.edu.tr/burakk/lecturenotes/village2019lecturenotes.pdf).

As for 2 ↑↑ $\aleph_0$, this would depend on what $2^{\aleph_0}$ (as 2 × 2 × ...) is (note that 2 + 2 + ... as 2 × $\aleph_0$ = $\aleph_0$). Presumably, it would be some $\kappa$ greater than $\aleph_0$, but how much so? We wouldn't know...