# Which one is bigger, infinity sign(∞) or aleph number?

Tags: infinity

the infinity sign(∞) is often used casually but it is very abstract concept and ill-defined... when there are 'infinite' natural numbers and aleph-zero is cardinality of a set of natural numbers..
is ∞ bigger than aleph-zero? or smaller?
or it can't be compared?

Comment: If in your case $\infty$ denotes the cardinal number of the reals, then it's bigger than $\aleph_0$.

Comment: That is the most poignant example of comparing apples to dead snails saturated with salt, that I have ever seen.

Comment: @T_M: How do you figure?

Comment: He said "the infinity sign". There is absolutely no way I could tell what he means by that, so IF he means that $\infty$ is continuum, then it's bigger. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @T_M: And if the OP means the cardinality of the natural numbers?

Comment: Well I really don't see how I could have written "If in your case..." any better. That's also the reason that I posted it as a comment, not an answer, I was assuming. @AsafKaragila

Comment: "...but it is very abstract concept and ill-defined..." With all due respect, and without intention to be inflammatory, I think it's your understanding of infinity that's "ill-defined."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinity has a context. Like everything else in mathematics. The $\infty$ sign in calculus is more order theoretic than anything else, signifying that something grows unbound. This is why it's not an issue using it for limits of functions of the reals, and limits of sequences of the natural numbers.

Cardinal numbers are something completely different. They come to give some notion of a size of a set.

Asking which one is bigger is missing the fact they don't even "share the same meaning" as far as infinities go.

You might also be interested in [The Aleph numbers and infinity in calculus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90758/the-aleph-numbers-and-infinity-in-calculus)