# How could I prove $\omega_1$ is an uncountable ordinal without appealing to Foundation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

During my course on elementary set theory, we defined $\omega_1$ to be the set of all countable ordinals. Now with Foundation we know that $\omega_1$ cannot be countable since that otherwise means $\omega_1\in \omega_1$, which just violates Axiom of Foundation. Now the question is can we prove $\omega_1$ is uncountable without using Foundation?

How should I proceed? This was a past paper question that did not worth so many marks and so I was wondering if there is a really slick way of showing this. I thought about using the criterion that a set is countable if and only if there exists a surjective function from $\omega$ to this set / if and only if there exists an injective function from this set to $\omega$ but I am stuck after some initial thoughts.

Many thanks in advance for any helps!

Comment: See relatedly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46833/how-do-we-know-an-aleph-1-exists-at-all/46836#46836)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinal is by definition strictly totally ordered by $\in$.  So this means that $\alpha\not\in\alpha$ for any ordinal $\alpha$: if $\alpha\in\alpha$, then $x=\alpha$ is an element of $\alpha$ that satisfies $x\in x$, contradicting antisymmetry of the strict total order $\in$ on $\alpha$.

Now if $\omega_1$ were an element of $\omega_1$, then by definition $\omega_1$ would be a countable ordinal, and in particular it would be an ordinal.  But an ordinal cannot be an element of itself, so this is a contradiction.

(Alternatively, if you already know that $\omega_1$ is an ordinal, you can just directly conclude that $\omega_1\not\in\omega_1$.  But proving that $\omega_1$ is an ordinal takes a lot of work and is much harder than the argument by contradiction as above.  That said, if you have managed to already prove that $\omega_1$ is a set at all then probably you have the machinery needed to quickly conclude that it is an ordinal.)

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much Eric! That makes sense! However, my course only defined the ordinal to be well ordered by $\in, =$ and so I don't quite have the notion of strict order. Wondering how could I adapt your argument to suit this definition?

Comment: Oof, that's an awful definition of ordinals.  It just doesn't work in the absence of Foundation at all.  For instance, in a model where there is a set $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$, then $x$ will be an ordinal by that definition.

Comment: In particular, using that definition in the absence of Foundation, you can't even prove that $\omega_1$ is a set.